# MySQL match all occurrences of a string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I am facing problems with matching string in a mysql query, I am using Laravel. My problem lies in this line

```
-> where ('service', 'like', '%'. $request->get('service') . '%')
```

My requested service is `hair cut women`and my `service` at the database is `Hair Women Style & Cut`. For some reason, these two strings are not matching.

So,

`play game` won't match with `play good two & game`

Is the above query supposed to work with this match? Is the special charecter `&`  hindering the match? I am not experienced with MySQL so I am seeking help.

Comment: Sorry, that isn't how LIKE works. `LIKE %two words%` means that it has to contain the exact text `two words` with 0 or more arbitrary characters on either side. So, for example, it will match `these two words here`, but not `two other words`.

Comment: using `%` on both side means exact just use either on right or left depends on your goal but you need to follow the order of words in your database too

Comment: `"%hair cut women%"` wont match `Hair Women Style & Cut` because the words aren't in the right order, if it was `Hair Cut Women Style & Cut` then it would match. You might want to have a lookat what the wildcards `%` actually do.

Comment: You could use `REGEXP 'play|game'`  read ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html )

Comment: If advanced searches are going to be something you aspire to offer then use a sensible way like index your documents in a search service like SOLR or ElasticSearch.

Comment: Can I use SOLR or ElasticSearch with my SQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%string%` matches `string` with 0 or more characters before and after it.
`%hair cut%` will match `cool hair cut` but not `hair for cut` because there is an unmatching word mixed in

if you wish to match words then you have to split the search term and create multiple where clauses.

```
$terms = explode(" ", $request->get('service'));
for ($terms as $term)
    $query->where('service', 'like', '%'. $term . '%')
```

the resulting query will be similar to

```
WHERE service LIKE '%hair%' AND service LIKE '%cut%'
```

Comment: But. I assume this is going to be slow and not scalable? I read somewhere that using two wildcards in like is not good.

Comment: the resulting query will be similar to `WHERE service like %hair% AND service LIKE %cut%`

Comment: This works for me, but I need to know if this is the best implementation.

Comment: well... for a regular website with average data amount (< 1,000,000) i think its good enough